# Receive IP packets on a TUN / TAP interface when the destination IP is not the IP assigned to the interface

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, ip, virtual

First of all, I create the virtual interface tuntap using commands:

```
#ip tuntap add inter_virt1 mode tap
#ip link set inter_virt1 up
#ifconfig inter_virt1 172.16.2.40/24
```

If I do ping over 172.16.2.40, I get response:

```
root@enri-VirtualBox:/home/enri# ping 172.16.2.40
PING 172.16.2.40 (172.16.2.40) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.2.40: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.2.40: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.2.40: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.110 ms
^C
--- 172.16.2.40 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.091/0.103/0.110/0.008 ms
```

However using the following code, I get not receive anything:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>          
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netpacket/packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h> 
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int fd, ret, j;
    struct sockaddr_ll interfaz;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    char *nameInterfaz = "inter_virt1";
    char buffer[5000];

    if((fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IP))) == -1){ 
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);    
    }

    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, nameInterfaz);

    if((ret = ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr)) == -1){
        perror("ioctl");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&interfaz, 0, sizeof(interfaz));
    interfaz.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    interfaz.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_IP);
    interfaz.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;

    if((ret = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&interfaz, sizeof(interfaz))) == -1){
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1){
        if((ret = recvfrom(fd, buffer, 5000, 0, NULL, NULL)) == -1){
            perror("recvfrom");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("%d bytes received\n", ret);
        for(j=0; j<ret; j++){
            printf("%d] %d, ", j, (unsigned char)buffer[j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried to send datagrams (UDP) to 172.16.2.40 using socket

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int sd;
        struct sockaddr_in dir_serv, dir_propia;
        char *dir_ip_serv = "172.16.2.40", dir_propia = "192.168.1.2";
        char buffer[2000];

        if((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1){
                perror("socket");
                exit(1);
        }

        memset((char *)&dir_serv, 0, sizeof(dir_serv));
        dir_serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
        dir_serv.sin_port = htons(7012);
        dir_serv.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(dir_ip_serv);

        memset((char *)&dir_propia, 0, sizeof(dir_propia));
        dir_propia.sin_family = AF_INET;
        dir_propia.sin_port = htons(7011);
        dir_propia.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(dir_ip_propia);

        if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&dir_propia, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1){
                perror("bind");
                exit(1);
        }

        printf("Introduce text\n");
        scanf("%s", buffer);

        if(sendto(sd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dir_serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1){
                perror("sendto");
                exit(1);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

But I do not get anything. My ultimate goal is to receive packets addressed to the virtual interface when the destination IP address is or is not the IP address assigned to the virtual interface.

Answer (score 0):

As a general point, if you use `SOCK_DGRAM` and `bind()` you will only receive packets addressed to the interface's IP address, as you are letting the kernel process the packet at the IP layer. The kernel will (broadly speaking) only relay packets addressed to a local interface IP address to the upper layers, and then will either forward (using the routing table) or discard other packets, depending on whether ip forwarding has been set up.

If you want to receive packets that are not addressed to the interface in question you should remove the IP numbering from the tunnel interface and use `SOCK_RAW` (see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw) for details) or `pcap` (see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap) for details) to receive them.

I *think* what you are trying to do is a third way to do this, i.e. use a `tun/tap` device. Here you need to route the packets into the `tun` / `tap` device, and your user mode code needs to read the user end of that. But your code does not appear to be doing that. In order to do this, *you* need to allocate the `tun/tap` device. See for instance [here](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs/VPN/files/simpletun.c) (see how `tun_fd` is produced from `tun_alloc`). You can't just bind to the interface side of the tun/tap device and magically assume it will work.

Comment: Finally, the program has worked using tun_allow to create the virtual interface type TUN [TAP type did not work], with system("ip link set tun1 up"); system("ifconfig tun1 192.168.2.40/24"); After that you can use read (fd, buffer, 2000) and write (fd, buffer, 2000)